# fable package error: no applicable method for 'model' applied to

Tags: r, time-series, arima, fable-r

Here is my code:

```
library(fpp3)
val <- seq(1,100,1)
time <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"),  by = "day", length.out =  100 )
df <- data.frame(val = val, time = time)
fit <- df %>% as_tibble(., index = time) %>%
  model(arima = ARIMA(val))
```

It generates error:

```
Error in UseMethod("model") : 
  no applicable method for 'model' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I do not see how it is different from this [fable example](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/fable/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we, need `as_tsibble` instead of `as_tibble`.  According to `?model`

> .data - A data structure suitable for the models (such as a tsibble)

```
library(dplyr)
library(fpp3)
df %>% 
    as_tsibble(., index = time) %>% 
    model(arima = ARIMA(val))
# A mable: 1 x 1
#           arima
#         <model>
#1 <ARIMA(0,1,0)>
```

Comment: Thank you! They really have to stop using such similar names! My bad!